What can I do with a free X (Twitter) Developers account?
After running the code below,
import tweepy

# Your Twitter API credentials
consumer_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'  # API Key
consumer_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'  # API Key Secret
bearer_token = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
access_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
access_token_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

# Set up the Tweepy client with OAuth 2.0 Bearer Token
client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=bearer_token)

# Function to fetch recent tweets from a user's timeline using Twitter API v2
def fetch_recent_tweets(username, count=5):
    try:
        # Get user ID by username
        user = client.get_user(username=username)
        user_id = user.data.id
        
        # Fetch tweets
        tweets = client.get_users_tweets(id=user_id, max_results=count)
        
        # Print tweets
        if tweets.data:
            for tweet in tweets.data:
                print(f"Tweet ID: {tweet.id} - {tweet.text}\n")
        else:
            print("No tweets found for this user.")
    
    except tweepy.TweepyException as e:
        print(f"Failed to fetch tweets: {e}")

# Example usage
fetch_recent_tweets("TwitterDev", count=5)

I got error message
Failed to fetch tweets: 403 Forbidden
When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal.

Do I need to change something here, or what I can do with a free account?


